# Object get updated in database automatically

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

I'm using `Spring data jpa` and `spring mvc` And i noticed that my object `contact` is updated in database automatically.

Here's My Code :

```
@Transactional
@Controller
public class ContactController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/update_contact ") 
    public @ResponseBody
    String update_contact (...) {
        ...
        Contact contact = contactrespository.findOne(idcontact);

        contact.setName(...);
        ...

    }
}
```

And without executing `contactrespository.save(idcontact);` My `contact` has been changed when i checked the database !
Can you explain me Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many [states](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/fr/html/objectstate.html) of an Object :

- **Persistent**: a persistent instance has a representation in the database and an identifier value and it is associated with a Hibernate Session.
- **Detached** : a detached instance is an object that has been persistent, but its Session has been closed.
- **transient**:  an object is transient if it has just been instantiated using the new operator, and it is not associated with a Hibernate Session.

In this context The changes are committed to contact because it is a persistent object that has been modified within a transaction because your controller is annotated with `@Transactional` so it's associated with a Hibernate Session.

It is not a good practice to annotate a `Controller` with `Transactional` annotation, it is better used on the service Layer where we invoke the `repository` not in the controller layer

```
    @Controller
    public class MyController{

        @Autowired
        private MyService service;

        @RequestMapping ....
        public Contact findContact(String name, ....){
        Contact contact =  service.get(...);
         // other logic 
         }
     }




    @Service
    public class MyService{

        @Autowired
        private MyRepository repository;

        @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS)
        public Contact get(long id){
         // better throw a notFuondException in here 
        return repository.findOne(id);
        }
    //same for other method like create and update with @Transactional REQUIRED NEW  or      REQUIRED propagation
   }
```

Comment: yes i know they say it's better to put `Transactional` on service layer but it's not a obligation. So even i'll make a service layer like you said i will have the same behavior  -> the object will get updated automatically.

Comment: i said it is not a good practice,you risk dirty reads and a mass overflow connections to database, means every time a client loads the page a change is made to the database !! its MVC, it supposed to be light weighted and independent from the persistence layer,it suppose to be a Client to the persistence layer which means to the services.

Comment: thanks for the information So do you mean even if i don't make something like `contactrespository.findOne(idcontact)` in my Controller  the connection will be opened to the database ?

Comment: But your answer didn't explain my issue ... your answer is just a advise because even if I put a service layer my issue will still remain.

Comment: findOne will return a `Persistent` instance of Contact , means every change made to this instance will be applied to the database.no change will be maid if the instance is `Detached`

Comment: The service layer also will be annotated as `@Transactional` so like you said in your answer `@Transactional` it's the problem ...

Comment: Yes but in your service Layer, you have more control, like the propagation , the isolation and exception handler ... you can even cache the responses of your services to minimize access to your database, and you can use services to build a web service API + easy to maintain code ....

Comment: i want just understand one thing ... if we annotated a class or method as `@Transactional` we don't need to `contactrespository.save(idcontact);` to update a object ? (in spring data save() on an object with predefined id will update the corresponding database record rather than insert a new one)

Comment: no but you didn't explain me why my object get updated without `contactrespository.save(idcontact);` ( `save()` = update in spring data). In your answer you just said that using service layer is good.

Comment: I said cause the Object is a `Persistent` instance, that's why every change will be automatically saved within the database, and it is persistent cause it is fetched by `findOne`

Comment: now i understand thanks a lot @ShadowRay  ... but in your answer you didn't explain well about the `Persistent`, `Transient` and `Detached` .. can you edit it for the future people who will have this issue.

Comment: If you just put the edit part first it will be great because it's the part that explain my question ;-)

Comment: thanks but you didn't mention that with `@Transactional` on controller a session will be opened so we will have PERSISTENT object so every change will be automatically saved within the database :-) i'm just concern about future user that's why I ask you to edit you answer :)

Comment: that's pretty obvious :) no need to be mentioned i guess

Comment: No i assure that yes .. me at first time i didn't get it just after many comments of you ;-)